# decimal numbers validation fail

Tags: regex, vb.net

I should create a regular expression that match all following values.. these values are percentages, so max value is 100:

- `1`
- `1.`
- `1.11`

I do not manage to match "`1.`".

I have tried different regular expression... but with no success... I think the one nearest to the solution is

```
(\d{1,2})|((\d{1,2})(\.)?((\d{1,5})?))
```

But it still does not work...

Does anyone can help me please?

Comment: No, because it would match also "1.," because "1.", is parsed "1.00"

Comment: I'm sorry... i'm using vb.net and im not expert of it... I was using cdbl.... tryparse works, but used with the following regex `(?n)^((100?|\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,5}))$`

Comment: @Ciccio The question Wayne is asking is, why use RegEx when a Float.TryParse will work with less confusion.

Comment: Because the value is a percentage... so i need a regular expression!

Comment: 1.0? You don't need a regex for that - `Float.TryParse` (or if you *know* it's valid, just Parse) converts the number to a floating point. If you need to multiply it by 100 to get it to the value you really want... well, do so!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
\b(?:100|\d\d?(?:\.\d{0,5})?)\b
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches your test cases, plus a few more edge cases:

```
(?<=^|\s)(?=[\d.])(100|\d{0,2})(\.\d{0,5})?(?=\s|$)
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/ISJdFu4hMr) matching all of these:

```
.1
.12345
0.1
1
1.
1.11
12
99
100
```

But not:

```
(blank)
12.123456
111
1111
```